# Cronjob inside Docker container doesn't run

Tags: docker, cron, alpine-linux

I have this crontab:

```
# do daily/weekly/monthly maintenance
# min   hour    day month   weekday command
*/15    *   *   *   *   run-parts /etc/periodic/15min
0   *   *   *   *   run-parts /etc/periodic/hourly
0   2   *   *   *   run-parts /etc/periodic/daily
0   3   *   *   6   run-parts /etc/periodic/weekly
0   5   1   *   *   run-parts /etc/periodic/monthly
*   *   *   *   *   run-parts /etc/periodic/test
```

/etc/periodic/test/test.sh

```
#! /bin/sh

echo test
```

Why it's not running? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you have to remove the .sh extension. run-parts won´t work with extensions

Comment: That was a critical information, thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

your cronjob is not clear, but here is the simples example that will run `hello from cronjob` after 15 minutes.

```
FROM alpine
RUN echo "*/15 * * * * echo \"hello from cronjob\" " | crontab - 
CMD ["crond","-f"]
```